# How to call a set session without displaying blank

Tags: php, html, session, isset

Im filling a selection box with a session, im then attempting to call this selection box to fill another with the same result. However its returning blank.
i know the session is setting because i can see it in the desired selection box, however i cant call it again and pass it to the other without it returning blank.

//my html where im including the external php.

```
  <form class="seed-form" method="POST" action="action/matchup1-action.php">
    <label name="round2-team1" class="round2-teams">
      <?php include_once "action/winner-script5.php";?>
    </label>
```

//the matchup 1 script that is called.

```
if (isset($_POST['go5'])) { // MATCHUP 5 SECOND ROUND MATCHUP 1

  include_once 'dbcon.php';

  $_SESSION['t_team9'] = $_POST['team-9'];
  $_SESSION['t_team10'] = $_POST['team-10'];
  $_SESSION['s_score9'] = $_POST['score-9'];
  $_SESSION['s_score10'] = $_POST['score-10'];
  header("Location: ../tables.php?tables=winner5");
}
```

//the script that is calling the session from its current selection box

```
<?php

  include_once "dbcon.php";

  //PERFORMING CHECK IF ALL REQUIRED SESSION VARIABLES ARE SET
  if (isset($_SESSION['s_score9'], $_SESSION['s_score10'], $_SESSION['t_team9'], $_SESSION['t_team10'])) {
    $team1 = $_SESSION['t_team9'];
    $team2 = $_SESSION['t_team10'];
    $score1 = $_SESSION['s_score9'];
    $score2 = $_SESSION['s_score10'];

    if ($score1 == $score2) {
      header("Location: tables.php?table=draw"); //CHECKS IF MATCH IS A DRAW, CANNOT BE A DRAW
      exit();
    }else {
      if ($score1 > $score2){
        echo $_SESSION['t_team9'];
      }else {
        echo $_SESSION['t_team10'];

      }
    }
  }else {
  echo "-";
}
?>
```

// where i want the session variable to output

```
<label name="round2-team1" class="round2-teams">
          <?php include_once "action/winner-script5.php";?>
        </label>
```

Comment: Where is the call to session_start() ? Do you 'start' the session somewhere?

Comment: yes its at the top of all the docs that require it, the session is being set, its just on that last php script where it claims to be unset

Comment: because its an include it just states the session is already started so it ignores it if i place it at the top of my session script

Comment: Why don't you combine your if statement into an `if elseif else` on the script that's called? Are you saying that where you want the output to be you're just getting your error echo'ed, which in this case is just `-`?